# Returning a file to a WSGI GET request

Tags: python, forms, download, get, wsgi

I'm new to WSGI on python; but have a windows server that's got isapi_wsgi installed on it. I also have a script that handles my GET requests all up and running great. The thing is, someone sends me a request, and I need to return a zip file to the requester. The following code is in my GET handler and it works, but doesn't seem like the right way to return the zipfile:

```
  # open zip file return it
  fin = open(zOutFilename, "rb")
  start_response( "200 OK", [('Content-Type', 'application/zip')])
  return fin.read()
```

The thing is, you're returning a 'stream' - which means you lose the filename (the browser simply names it the name of the GET query) and it seems awfully slow.

Is there a better way to return a file for download with wsgi then this method?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Taken directly from [PEP 333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#optional-platform-specific-file-handling):

```
if 'wsgi.file_wrapper' in environ:
    return environ['wsgi.file_wrapper'](filelike, block_size)
else:
    return iter(lambda: filelike.read(block_size), '')
```

Also you probably want the [Content-Disposition](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) header for providing the file name to the client.

Comment: Yes yes - this is what I was looking for.  It fixed my problem:
<p>
           fin = open(zOutFilename, "rb")
           size = os.path.getsize(zOutFilename)
           start_response( "200 OK", [ ('Content-Type', 'application/zip'), ('Content-length', str(size)), ('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='+finalModelName+'.zip') ] ) 
           
           # return the entire file
           if 'wsgi.file_wrapper' in environ:
                return environ['wsgi.file_wrapper'](fin, 1024)
           else:
                return iter(lambda: fin.read(1024), '')
</p>